# Failed to start Hostname Service

Tags: boot

When I boot my system, I get a black screen with the following error message and can't login.

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Hostname Service.
See 'systemctl status systemd-hostnamed.service' for details. 
[  OK  ] Finished terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.
[  OK  ] Finished Set console scheme.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I also have this problem and the link provided by @Pilot6 doesn't have an answer to this (it doesn't even mention "hostname").